# Exercise on MLE with hypergeometric distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, hypergeometric-distribution

I am struggling with the following exercise from Stapleton's book (it's exercise 7.4.1).

> A box contains eight eggs, of which an unknown number $R$ are rotten.
> You take a simple random sample of three eggs. Let $X$ be the number
> of rotten eggs in the sample.
>
> - Find the MLE of $R$ (*Warning*: don't use calculus.)
> - What is the MLE for $E(X) = 3(R/8)$?

For the first question, we can compute the likelihood of having $X$ rotten samples given $R$ as:
$$
  p(X|R) = {R \choose X}{8 - R \choose 3 - X}/{8\choose 3}.
$$
This leads to the following table ($X$ changes along a column, $R$ along a row):
$$
\begin{array}{lccccccccc}
 X|R & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\hline
 0 & 1 & 0.625 & 0.357 & 0.179 & 0.0714 & 0.0179 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 1 & 0 & 0.375 & 0.536 & 0.536 & 0.429 & 0.268 & 0.107 & 0 & 0\\
 2 & 0 & 0 & 0.107 & 0.268 & 0.429 & 0.536 & 0.536 & 0.375 & 0\\
 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0179 & 0.0714 & 0.179 & 0.357 & 0.625 & 1
\end{array}
$$
In this case the maximum likelihood estimator would be $R=0$ for $X=0$, $R=8$ for $X=3$, but I do not understand how to choose one between $R=2$ and $R=3$ for $X=1$, given that both answers have the same likelihood.

For the second question, I am not sure.
I suspect I should compute the likelihood of $E(X)$ like this:

$$
  L(E(X)=\mu|R) = \sum_{i=0}^3 i\cdot p(i|R),
$$
where $p(i|R)$ can be read on the table above.
But maybe I am misunderstanding the question.

Comment: If likelihood is maximized for two values of $R$, then both are MLE. For the second question, use invariance/equivariance of MLE.

Comment: Please add `self-study` as a tag.

Comment: @StubbornAtom good point, so I should just say that the MLE estimate of $E(X)$ is just $3/8$ times whatever is the MLE estimate of $R$? This follows from the theorem you mention and a quick check that $E(X)$ is a one-to-one function of $R$.

Comment: Yes, but invariance property holds for *any* function of MLE.